# Android: how to show the option menu icons in above api level 16 to 21?

Tags: android, optionmenu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/myicon"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_32"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/login"/>
```

i just tried this but not showing icon only shows the text on Moto E

Comment: Please post your activity as well.

Answer (score 1):

If in case your device has an option/menu button that would open the menu,Android will not show the three dotted lines in your actionbar.